# Any efficient way to handle huge HTML files(approx 50MB)?

Tags: html, disassembly

I am implementing a disassembler for Gameboy ROM images. The output of the disassembler is a HTML file where you could see the hex dump and disassembly.

Currently I implemented the hex dump part and the HTML(which shows address, hex values and ascii) which I got was nearly 50MB in size(Gameboy ROM is 8MB in size). It takes really long time for the browser to load. If I add the disassembled code, it would become double in size.

Is there an efficient way to handle this situation ? I thought of splitting the HTML files but I don't prefer that. Can I do something with JavaScript to increase performance (may be load small amounts of data as user requests )? I am a newbie to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading, converting and displaying 50MB of HTML just takes very long. This effect is even bigger when the content is placed in one or more huge tables (which take long to calculate and render).

The question you should ask yourself is: do I really need HTML to display this fine, or can I also do this with one of the following file types:

- Plain Text, a little formatted (fast if you use a text editor that buffers the input, like Notepad++);
- XML (better structured, still slow, but less);
- CSV if it is one giant list of tabular data.

Comment: Perhaps even [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) formatting for plain text, depending on formatting options he needs.

Comment: @BergQuester: I don't know it, but sounds promising.

Comment: Sure you do, [StackExchange comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) use it. ;-) Actually, I misspoke. I was thinking about [MultiMarkdown](https://github.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown/wiki/MultiMarkdown-Syntax-Guide), a Markdown extension that adds tables, etc.

Comment: I know SE uses it, but I am not personally familiar with it.

Comment: @BergQuester but this would also create a huge HTML file after parsing the markdown text